# Getting device or resource busy when trying to write to virtual serial port?

Tags: c#, linux, serial-port, socat

Please bear in mind that I am fairly inexperienced in C#. So, I've been trying to write to a virtual serial port but I keep getting a `Device or resource busy` error. The virtual port I am connecting to is created using the following command:

`socat -d -d -v pty,rawer,link=/tmp/testPort EXEC:tee,pty,rawer`

After creating the virtual port I run the following C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    SerialPort s = new SerialPort("/tmp/testPort");
    s.Open();
    Thread.Sleep(100000);
    s.Close();
}
```

I want to write afterwards to `/tmp/testPort` but I get the error. The reason I want to do this is because I want to simulate hardware sending data back to that serial port. I can do this when running on the terminal, by simply using `cat` to "read" data and `echo hey > /tmp/testPort` to "write" data.

My guess is the file is being locked by the script and won't allow me to write.

Any input would point me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!